Drawing inscribed concentric circles in a rectangle
I'm trying to inscribe using tikz a serie of concentric circles in a rectangle in such a way that the part of the circle outside the limits of the rectangle were not visible May someone help me?

Did you try something? This looks pretty straight forward with clipping.

If you can't figure out the clipping, post code for the picture without the clipping and somebody will add it for you.

See the online TikZ manual on clip: https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#pgf./tikz/clip . Please provide some code to better show the concrete problem you have.

Like this:

Code (as already suggested @cfr):
\documentclass[tikz,border=.5cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \clip[draw] (-2,-3) rectangle (2,3);%omit [draw] if you dont want to draw the rectangle
    \foreach \r in {.2,.4,...,3} \draw circle(\r);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

